# Mordell's Theorem and $nP=Q$ for given $P,Q$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, abelian-varieties

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve given by an equation $E : y^2 = x^3 + Ax + B$ with $A, B \in  Q$. Then the group of rational points E(Q) is a finitely generated abelian group. In other words, there is a
finite set of points P1, . . . , Pt ∈ E(Q) so that every point $P ∈ E(Q)$ can be written in the form $P = n_1P_1 + n_2P_2 + · · · + n_tP_t$ for some $n_1, n_2, . . . , n_t ∈ Z$. This is Mordell's Theorem (1922).

Does above theorem guarantees that  $nP=Q$ for given $P, Q$, where $P,Q \in E$ ?

If not then  what is the condition for  $n$ such that  $nP=Q$ for $P,Q \in E$?

Comment: If you mean whether for any points $P,Q$ there exists an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $P=nQ$ then it is definitely a ‘no’. For example some elements may have infinite order and some others belong to the torsion subgroup

Comment: @ΜάρκοςΚαραμέρης the points in torsoin group satisfies the condition above?

Comment: No not in general, the condition you imposed is that point $Q$ is in the orbit of $P$ specifically which can fail if your torsion group is for example isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times{}\mathbb{Z}_2$

Comment: I think you need some experience with pencil and paper, doing computations on more than one chosen elliptic curve. You’ll find that it helps a lot.